# How do I know if the iPad bluetooth keyboard is used when UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is broadcasted?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

The notification `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is correctly broadcasted when a keyboard is available to the user.

I have my delegate method invoked when this happens, but how do I know if it is bluetooth keyboard or not ?

thanks

**UPDATE**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
 object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That notification (UIKeyboardWillShowNotification) will NOT be broadcast if a bluetooth keyboard is present unless you have an inputAccessoryView.  That, in fact, is the only way to know.  If you are using this to adjust views for the software keyboard, you should handle that based on this notification and you will always be ok.

Otherwise you can check the keyboard size differences in the userInfo property of the notification.

Comment: I can assure you that the notification is broadcast even with a bluetooth keyboard connected. I've just tried now, with a physical bluetooth keyboard and I've updated my question so you can see my observer.

Comment: That means you have an inputAccessoryView assigned to your textfield.  Otherwise you wouldn't get the notification.  Check the size of the keyboard to know.

Comment: Yes, I have inputAccessory indeed. Is there a way to know anyway ? Maybe looking at the frame of inputAccessory ?

Comment: Use the userInfo from the notification:[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]

Comment: I see a difference: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 982}, {768, 306}}"; and "NSRect: {{0, 982}, {768, 306}}"; But what code should I write ? To compare the y value with an hardcoded value ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to be identical.  Are you sure?  Try using this:  [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]  The width/height can change in different orientations too, so make sure you test in both landscape and portrait.  I haven't encountered this issue personally, so I don't have a perfect solid solution, just trying to help you figure it out...

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake of copy/paste the first one is: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 718}, {768, 306}}"; How can I compare these values without hardcoding a value in the code ?

Comment: I think you'll have to use a hard-coded value, but I think that's reasonable here since that value will be zero.  I would test to ensure this logic always holds, but you should have a zero value for the bluetooth keyboard.  That value may change position as you change orientation.  I believe there are some private API methods you can use to actually detect the bluetooth keyboard, but your app would not be approved if you used them.  This is the only public and approved approach I know of...

Comment: But in the example I gave you, the value is 718 for hardware keyboard and 982 without keyboard. Why do you say 0 ?

Comment: Interesting.  I really didn't expect these results.  I misinterpreted the Rects you were getting.  IF you can't do it this way, I'm not sure how to do it.  I don't understand how it can return a frame for a keyboard that's not appearing.  This is the only approach I know of, but I have not tested any of this myself... obviously...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to get rid of the inputAccessoryView.  You can still show your view but instead of letting it happen automatically (via inputAccessoryView), you could trigger on the keyboardWillShow notification, and in that case you would know what you have.  If you can't use the size of keyboard from notification, I see this as your only option.

Comment: It wouldn't be a terrible idea to file a bug report to apple either.  This seems like common functionality they should provide a public API for.

Comment: You are actually right. In the case of the screen keyboard, if the landscape is on left side, origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=394, height=1024) and right side: origin=(x=374, y=0) size=(width=394, height=1024).

Comment: Another example: HARDWARE keyboard + portrait:  UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 982}, {768, 306}}";. HARDWARE + potrait upside down = CGRect) $2 = origin=(x=0, y= - 264) size=(width=768, height=306)

Comment: So it apparently change saccording to the specific orientation of the device.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19483/discussion-between-hackystack-and-patrick)

Comment: FWIW I use a bluetooth keyboard, I do NOT use inputAccessoryView and the notification triggers. Moreover, UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey reports the same size with or without a physical keyboard attached. On the other hand, the Y offset is different.

Answer (score 1):

The information is available in the userInfo dictionary, it just requires some manipulation to get what you want.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
CGRect startKeyboardRect  = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect finishKeyboardRect = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

startKeyboardRect   = [self.view convertRect:startKeyboardRect fromView:self.view.window];
finishKeyboardRect  = [self.view convertRect:finishKeyboardRect  fromView:self.view.window];

CGFloat vertShuffle = startKeyboardRect.origin.y - finishKeyboardRect.origin.y;
```